# MASM alternative for NASM padding to 510 bytes with times 510 - ($-$$) db 0

Tags: assembly, nasm, padding, masm, bootloader

What will be the **MASM** alternative for this NASM statement?

```
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
```

I was making a MBR bootloader. Basically this statement fills up the remaining 510 bytes on memory with 0 as a bootloader should be 512 bytes in size.

Comment: It's code often found at the end of bootsectors, it zero-pads the executable to 512 bytes so that it fits exactly inside the MBR.

Comment: Jasper Bekkers, Any alternative for MASM for this?

Comment: I don't know, but it should be easy enough to create a tool that does this. It should be like 5 lines of code maximum, just add zero bytes at the end until you're at 512 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
code segment use16
assume cs:code
org 7c00h
start:

; your code
db 510-($-start) dup(0)
dw 0AA55h

code ends
end start
```

Another alternative is using `org` to actually *seek* in the output file, [mentioned by the NASM manual](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdo12.html#section-12.1.3) as something that works in MASM but not NASM:

```
; MASM only
        ORG 0 

        ; some boot sector code 

        ORG 510 
        DW 0xAA55
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped. Finally 1 last request, can you explain to me this line of code : TIMES 0Bh-$+start DB 0. I know what times does and even what $ means, even the DB 0 part. But can you simplify the rest of it for me - 0BH and start(name of a segment).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is that you don't understand.

Comment: Basically i dont understand what 0bh or 0xb is. And what the final outcome is. For eg. $-$$ is the size of the program same way, what does 0bh-$+start evaluate to?

Comment: 0Bh and 0xB are hexadecimal numbers. Ever heard of those? I have no idea what `0bh-$+start` will evaluate to (I'm not even completely sure it's valid, but I'm not going to explain why I'm not sure, that's not related) without seeing the code, where it's used.

Comment: Thank you, I'll add the screenshot of the code asap. Please help me if you can. Thanks again.

Comment: That'll have to be a new question, though.

Comment: `0bh - $ + start` = `0bh - ($ - start)`, if that helps. It adds padding just like the first one. No idea what this one's good for, though! Edit: `0bh - (start - $)` I mean!

Comment: Thank you guys, I will add a new question about this 1. Please help me figure out this line of code. And I'll include the whole program there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906924/explanation-of-a-few-lines-in-assembly - This is the new question, please answer it. The code is entered there. Thanks in advance all.