# Explanation of a few lines in Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

```
bits 16

org 0x7c00

start: jmp loader

;******; ; OEM Parameter block ;********;

TIMES 0Bh-$+start DB 0; THIS LINE

bpbBytesPerSector: DW 512 

bpbSectorsPerCluster: DB 1

bpbReservedSectors: DW 1

bpbNumberOfFATs: DB 2 

bpbRootEntries: DW 224 

bpbTotalSectors: DW 2880 

bpbMedia: DB 0xF0 

bpbSectorsPerFAT: DW 9 

bpbSectorsPerTrack: DW 18

bpbHeadsPerCylinder: DW 2

bpbHiddenSectors: DD 0 

bpbTotalSectorsBig: DD 0 

bsDriveNumber: DB 0 

bsUnused: DB 0 

bsExtBootSignature: DB 0x29 

bsSerialNumber: DD 0xa0a1a2a3 

bsVolumeLabel: DB "MOS FLOPPY "

bsFileSystem: DB "FAT12   "

;******** ; Bootloader Entry Point ;**********;

loader:

cli 

hlt 

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0 

dw 0xAA55
```

Now the problem is I don't quite understand what TIMES 0bh-$+start evaluates to in this case.
For Example $-$$ = size of the program.
Also it will be really heĺpful if someone can explain to me the LODSB Syntax. Also why is there a : sign after each of those bpb and bs statements? Doesn't the : sign mean the beginning of a new section, just as in case of loader section or start section in this program.
Please explain in detail how the following evaluates to the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! "THIS LINE" just reserves space for "OEMNAME". Put the name of your OS there, if you like - padded to 11 bytes. ($$ is the same as "start" - beginning of section - 0x7C00 - in this case).

Not much "syntax" to `lodsb`, it's just an instruction...
http://home.myfairpoint.net/fbkotler/nasmdocc.html#section-A.4.141
(did I confuse you using "lodbs" as an example of a typoed instruction? Sorry.)

The ":" does absolutely nothing. In the case of a label alone on a line, it informs Nasm that it is intended to be a label, and isn't a typoed instruction. Look in the Manual for "orphan_label". Nasm will (optionally - default ON) warn if there's no ":", but does the right thing anyway.

You really ought to have a `nop` after `jmp start`, since Nasm will emit a "short" `jmp` (older versions of Nasm defaulted to a near `jmp`). Since the entire purpose of "THIS LINE" is to put the remaining BPB variables in the right place, might as well do it!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I want to understand that statement better (THIS LINE) and its working, if possible step by step. Please help me. Also, what is the maximum size the OS name can have?

Comment: And by step by step I mean I don't understand what 0bh-$+start evaluates to. 0bh-($-start) may be an approach, but $ is the address of the current line of code and start is declared 1 line earlier, hence it possibly results to 1. 0bh(I don't know why this random hex is there) - 1 = (Taking it as hex B which is 11 - 1) 10 (decimal) . But how come is it resulting to 11 (I may be wrong). This is what I want to know. Thanks.

Comment: And also why 11 bytes? The name of your OS should be 8 bytes long right?

Comment: Right. 8 bytes for the name. BPB should start 3 bytes into the bootsector. The expression should account for a two-byte `jmp` or a three-byte `jmp`. Forget what I said about needing the `nop`. `start` (or `$$`) is 7C00h, `$` is 2 (should be 3). Just puts `bpbBytesPerSector` in the right place...

Comment: You might be well served by reading the [Microsoft FAT/FAT32 file system specification](http://read.pudn.com/downloads77/ebook/294884/FAT32%20Spec%20(SDA%20Contribution).pdf) if you are still making a project out of this.  It is from 2004, but the information is still relevant.